# Download tiles using custom WMTS provider

Tags: r, wmts, mapview

I'm using a WMTS layer in QGIS. Everything works fine. Now I would like to get access to the images in R both using `maptiles` and `mapview`. I do not know the WMTS standard and consequently I hardly understand the layer capability metadata but I eventually built a valid url from that xml file. The code do download something but it is always in a somewhat random location. The XML capability file is [here](https://servicesmatriciels.mern.gouv.qc.ca/erdas-iws/ogc/wmts/Inventaire_Ecoforestier?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0&service=WMTS).

```r
library(maptiles)
library(sf)

p = st_point(c(63500, 624900))
p = st_sfc(p)
p = st_set_crs(p, 32198)
p = st_transform(p, 4326)
bb = st_bbox(st_buffer(p, 300))

# Good
rgb = get_tiles(bb, provider = "Esri.WorldImagery")
library(terra)
plot(rgb)

mffp <- list(
  src = 'Aerial photography',
  q = 'https://servicesmatriciels.mern.gouv.qc.ca:443/erdas-iws/ogc/wmts/Inventaire_Ecoforestier/Inventaire_Ecoforestier/default/OGC:1.0:GlobalCRS84Pixel/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
  sub = NA,
  cit = ''
)

# In the ocean (maybe)
rgb = get_tiles(bb, provider = mffp)
plot(rgb)
```

Notice that I'm keen to bypass `maptile` and do the math myself to retrieve the tiles if necessary but at this stage I don't even know what to compute. Also I did not find yet how to add a provider in `mapview` but if I can work with `maptile` it's already good enough.

Comment: That WMTS seems to supply 5 different layers - some are global and some are just a bit of Canada. There's various different coordinate systems. I suspect `maptile` is expecting everything to be in Google Maps' Web Mercator... Have you tried the image URL for the `GoogleMapsCompatibleExt2:epsg:3857` tile set?

Comment: Yes, I reached the same conclusion. I tried `GoogleMapsCompatibleExt2:epsg:3857` but `maptile` is expecting lon/lat WGS84 (epsg:4326) so it does not works better in my tests. As I said I could do the math if I were able to figure out the proper inputs (bbox modulo 256px tiles + zoom resolution should be enough I guess) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x and y are the other way round for the Google Maps Compatible layer:

```
url="https://servicesmatriciels.mern.gouv.qc.ca:443/erdas-iws/ogc/wmts/Inventaire_Ecoforestier/Inventaire_Ecoforestier/default/GoogleMapsCompatibleExt2:epsg:3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg"
mffp = list(src="Aerial Photography", q=url, sub=NA, cit='')
rgb = get_tiles(bb, provider = mffp)
plot(rgb)
```

complains because there's some NAs in there:

```
Error in grDevices::rgb(RGB[, 1], RGB[, 2], RGB[, 3], alpha = alpha, maxColorValue = scale) : 
  color intensity NA, not in 0:255
```

whateven is a `SpatRaster` object anyway? Let's make it a raster package stack:

```
library(raster)
rgb = stack(rgb)
plotRGB(rgb)
```

[image]

(ah, `SpatRaster` is from the `terra` package. I guess there's a way to deal with NAs but I dunno yet. The `raster` package seems happy enough for now with NAs in there, and clearly the crux of the problem is solved.)

Figured this out by putting the URL into QGIS as an XYZ Tiles layer - this is what you get if the {x} and {y} are the wrong way round:

[image]

Comment: So simple. Thank you for your help